# Ubuntu EC2 server not accepting key following OpenSSH upgrade

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I've just upgraded OpenSSH on an EC2 Ubuntu instance.

sshd -V now gives: OpenSSH_6.6p1

previously showed: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.3

However, I can no longer log in with the .pem file from Amazon.

Its asking for a password, and auth.log shows me the following:

```
Sep  9 16:27:54 ip------0 sshd[31498]: rexec line 89: Unsupported option UsePAM
Sep  9 16:27:55 ip------0 sshd[31498]: User ubuntu not allowed because account is locked
Sep  9 16:27:55 ip------0 sshd[31498]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubuntu [preauth]
```

Comment: Undo your changes and don't try this again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok - I will take your advice and try to roll back changes but why should I not try this again?

Comment: Because it's a critical system component that you really need to understand thoroughly before you attempt to recompile and replace yourself. Not to mention there's no reason to do it anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The reason to do it was to satisfy security request, and I was asked to address the issues. Admittedly my knowledge is not great and a followed a post on the Ubuntu forum http://askubuntu.com/questions/461494/update-openssh-server-in-12-04

Comment: Remediating any actual security issues with a software package is generally handled by installing the backported update that the distribution provides. Again, there is no good reason to do this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is pretty clear:

```
User ubuntu not allowed because account is locked
```

SSH does not allow to log into locked account, whether with keys or password. Unlock user 'ubuntu':

```
passwd -u ubuntu
```

If you never set a password for the user before and don't intend to use one, still, don't leave it empty. Set some random password and forget it:

```
passwd    ubuntu
```

Comment: Best practices are to use ssh passwordless authentication whenever possible.

Comment: Yes - I need to regain access via a .pem file, ideally the original one - it seems that the upgrade has changed or added ssh keys.

Comment: The password is not set to use it for login, but to unlock the account (so SSH would allow the user in WITH KEY) without leaving it with an empty password!

Comment: If I might add: Really best practise is to notify security staff and to block further login attempts after a small number of failed ones to prevent brute force attacks, which basically elminates the difference of password based and key based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the **/etc/shadow** file. I am sure you would see `!` in the encrypted password column(2nd). I was able to resolve this issue by taking out the `!` from the password column. BTW, the auth logs complain about the account locked. (and `!` is normally used to lock the useraccount)

**/etc/shadow**

```
ubuntu:!$6$HmV2ibLf$s25xgRnrD6pbOVAcpzl45PPYhWKlyy.OauX2xadGrWWANGDZ66WpeglPryd14kX.IbKiKvFB2OA/CZY6ZG4U0/:15859:0:99999:7:::
```

It would look something like above. You take off the `!` in the second column and you should be able to login to the machine again as ubuntu user and the key used for it.

You can do all the above steps by detaching the root volume of your current instance and attaching it to another test instance. 
Mount the volume as secondary drive and then edit the **MOUNT/etc/shadow** file.